# download jquery.numeric.js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access the jquery.numeric.js file to use the $('#textbox').numeric() function. The jquery site link does not work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://code.webmonkey.uk.com/plugins/:

[jquery.numeric.zip](http://code.webmonkey.uk.com/plugins/jquery.numeric.zip)

Comment: how to make it not to allow '.' ? only integers

Comment: @levanlevi Please ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/numeric/jquery.numeric.js

Comment: This link copy and paste is one line code, and needs formatting.  Vote up, but the other is clean.  THanks !

Comment: @User: You can click the raw link on that page.  (https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/raw/master/numeric/jquery.numeric.js)

Answer (score 0):

here is the .min version of jquery.numeric.js

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('r.E.W=7(c,d){c=c||".";d=q d=="7"?d:7(){};6.K(7(e){g a=e.i?e.i:e.h?e.h:0;2(a==k&&6.N.J()=="G"){5 3}f 2(a==k){5 j}g b=j;2((e.4&&a==y)||(e.4&&a==v))5 3;2((e.4&&a==t)||(e.4&&a==u))5 3;2((e.4&&a==V)||(e.4&&a==S))5 3;2((e.4&&a==R)||(e.4&&a==Q))5 3;2((e.4&&a==P)||(e.4&&a==O)||(e.L&&a==p))5 3;2(a<I||a>H){2(a==p&&6.l.F==0)5 3;2(a==c.n(0)&&6.l.o(c)!=-1){b=j}2(a!=8&&a!=9&&a!=k&&a!=D&&a!=C&&a!=M&&a!=B&&a!=A){b=j}f{2(q e.i!="z"){2(e.h==e.m&&e.m!=0){b=3}f 2(e.h!=0&&e.i==0&&e.m==0){b=3}}}2(a==c.n(0)&&6.l.o(c)==-1){b=3}}f{b=3}5 b}).x(7(){g a=r(6).w();2(a!=""){g b=T U("^\\\\d+$|\\\\d*"+c+"\\\\d+");2(!b.s(a)){d.X(6)}}});5 6}',60,60,'||if|true|ctrlKey|return|this|function||||||||else|var|keyCode|charCode|false|13|value|which|charCodeAt|indexOf|45|typeof|jQuery|exec|120|88|65|val|blur|97|undefined|46|39|36|35|fn|length|input|57|48|toLowerCase|keypress|shiftKey|37|nodeName|86|118|90|122|67|new|RegExp|99|numeric|apply'.split('|'),0,{}))
```